# Forking laravel/framework while using Composer

Tags: php, git, laravel, version-control, composer-php

For some reason I can't find any instructions on how to fork laravel/framework and then using it inside Composer.

It seems that Composer cannot resolve dependencies for custom packages, so that complicates things.

So what I want to do is setup a new, clean Laravel installation while using a forked laravel/framework repo instead of the packagist laravel/framework package. How would I go about this?

This because I want to make some edits inside the Laravel core framework.

This is what I tried, and didn't work:

1. Fork Laravel/Framework inside GitHub
2. Install Laravel into an empty folder by using Composer
3. Edit composer.json and add your forked repo as a package:

   ```
   "repositories": [{
       "type": "package",
       "package": {
           "version": "dev-edits",
           "name": "laravel/framework",
           "source": {
               "url": "My forked GitHub URL",
               "type": "git",
               "reference": "dev-edits"
           }
       }
   }],
   ```

   And adding this as a requirement instead of the default packagist package:

   ```
   "laravel/framework": "dev-edits"
   ```
4. Run `composer update`

Problem here I think is that Composer doesn't resolve and install `laravel/framework` dependencies? Manually copying the `laravel/framework` requires from composer.json into mine gives me the following error:

`Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in....`

Comment: have you tried adding your forked project to your composer.json?

Comment: try cloning the laravel project instead of installing it by composer, then edit your composer to your repo and then run composer install

Comment: Only installs laravel/framework (no dependencies) and then gives the error ` Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in ...boostrap/autoload.php`.

Comment: @Basaa did you find any solution ?I'm looking for a work around too

Comment: @alex Nope. Still no solution.

Comment: use an alias, i mean replace `"laravel/framework": "dev-edits"` with `"laravel/framework": "dev-edits as 5.2.35"` or whatever version you prefer, it worked for me